# Windows Phone exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' was thrown

Tags: windows-phone

I have designed a sample app in windows phone. In that application I upload a file on a server and after uploading I just download that file from server. My problem is that While uploading a file to the server I press a screen lock key. When I release a lock I got the exception

```
System.Net.WebException: Exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' was thrown. ---> System.Net.WebException: Exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' was thrown.
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndGetResponse>b__d(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Demo.Pages.NetworkSpeedTest.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
```

It works fine if I didn't press scree lock key. How can I solve this? Any solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's normal, the default behavior on Windows Phone when locking the screen is to put the app in a dormant state in order to reduce power consumption.

If you want to override that behavior, you should use the following code:

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

Your app will be allowed to execude code even when the phone is locked.

More info on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941090%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: You can either put in in a specific page Construtor, or if you want it to be global to your app, put it in the InitializePhoneApplication method in App.xaml.cs.